# Looking for an optimized way of getting s3 info (for eg, policy) across regions

Tags: aws-sdk-go

I need to get properties of all S3 buckets across all regions, is there a single SDK api which can achieve this? As i end up creating per region session and calling s3 apis with those new sessions.

- Using ListBuckets, get the buckets list
- GetBucketLocation will give the location/region
- Create session per region
- Then make a s3 query using these new sessions per region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single API. Your approach is reasonable, but slow, unless you fire off a different thread for each session/region.